# Is QNX unix-like?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is QNX a unix? For the purpose of this site, that is. Is QNX on-topic here?

Related: [Are plan9 questions on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329/are-plan9-questions-on-topic)

Example: [Archive of QNX's use messages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39211/archive-of-qnxs-use-messages)

Answer (score 17):

I think it's fair to lump QNX in as Unix-like. It's posix, and the company touts easy portability from Unix/Linux as a feature. I don't know how much common ground questions we'd typically get would share, but failing a more-suited SE bucket for them I think it's okay for them to fid a home here.

Answer (score 4):

QNX is a realtime micro-kernel OS. It is Unix/Linux **like** and does support POSIX components, as stated here:

> The QNX® Neutrino® RTOS supports hundreds of POSIX commands, utilities, and programming interfaces that maximize code portability and reusability. This rich, standards-based environment includes familiar shells and command-line interfaces, and allows developers to quickly migrate Linux, Unix, and other open source programs to QNX.

They do have their own implementation of some shell utility functions, bare this in mind, as some functions might differ from std *nix system by their options or name.

Comment: QNX is not Linux. It has a POSIX interface, but then, so does Windows.

Comment: I had forgotten the 'like' in my post.