# Did we ever come to a consensus regarding Plan 9 questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've read [Are plan9 questions on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/329/29146), and it seems like there wasn't really a consensus. The discussion was started, but never really finished. Plus, that was a couple years ago, there are new people, etc.

So, are Plan 9 questions on-topic? [Plan 9 from Bell Labs book](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41272/29146) seems to indicate that they are, since it haven't been closed.

Other questions found by looking at [plan9](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plan9):

- [What aspects of Plan 9 have made their way into Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8337/29146) - this is a UNIX-focused question, not a Plan 9-focused question. Therefore, irrelevant to this discussion
- [How to run programs with arguments like 'arg=val' (e.g. dd) in rc shell (Linux version ported from Plan9 OS)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36216/29146) - this is about the port of `rc` to UNIX done as a part of plan9port. It is about `rc` on Linux, not Plan 9 in general. Therefore, irrelevant(ish) to this discussion
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8297/29146 - closed due to the fact that it was too broad, not due to the fact that it was about Plan 9. Therefore, not an indication of consensus, and therefore, irrelevant

If anyone thinks this question is unwarranted and [Are plan9 questions on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/329/29146) still represents community consensus, feel free to vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: can I boot directly to plan 9? does it have a kernel? if not what OS's can I run it on? are any of them unix? what is the answer if I substitute the words `plan 9` with anything else. IIRC plan 9 is little more than a different shell at this point? maybe some other pieces, but you're still booting on a non plan 9 kernel.

Comment: @xenoterracide in order: yes. yes. it runs on (some) virtual machines, and a spin-off called Inferno runs natively on a number of operating systems; there's also plan9port which aims to bring some Plan 9 things (e.g. the `rc` shell) to UNIX-like systems. as said above, plan9port runs on UNIX-like machines, and Inferno runs as a native app on UNIX-like machines. if you substitute Plan 9 w/ something else, the answer will likely be different. yes, it is; it's a full OS. Plan 9 has always, always had its own kernel.

Comment: I wasn't aware of anything other than the plan 9 port I guess... well then my answer is, I don't know, I guess it's unix like, though not a posixly system. It's a hard call, which is probably why it never got a decidedly answer, though it seems that most people voted up for it to be ok.

Comment: Related: [Is QNX unix-like?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/949/is-qnx-unix-like) (we've decided that yes) We also have a couple of [tag:hurd] questions.

Comment: Are we thumbing our nose at a kernel/OS written by Saint Ken?!??!  ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just judging by the votes on the previous question, people think that it's ok. I agree with @Gilles this site should not become "not windows", anymore than the questions about applications that are ok, should be judged as ok by "not windows". Basically we should never be "not windows". Plan 9 is Unixy in spirit, even if it's not POSIXy. I'm personally ok with it, given its relation to Unix.